# how to print this result using PHP

Tags: php

How to print this result using this code i didn't recognize myself what am i doing wrong can you please help me out

```
<?php
$brush_price = 5;

echo "<table border=\"1\" align=\"center\">";
echo "<tr><th>Quantity</th>";
echo "<th>Price</th></tr>";
for ( $counter++ = 10; $counter <= 100; $counter += 10) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $counter;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $brush_price * $counter;
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";    
?>
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
Quantity Price
10        50
20        100
30        150
```

Comment: `echo`? Do you want a PHP answer or JavaScript? Are you trying to ask how to use JavaScript to create a table that looks like the last four lines of your question, or...?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
for ( $counter = 10; $counter <= 100; $counter += 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: Same output, written in Javascript. Just put it in your html file.

```
var brush_price = 5;

document.write("<table border='1' align='center'>");
document.write("<tr><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th></tr>");

for(var counter = 10; counter <= 100; counter += 10){
    document.write("<tr><td>" + counter + "</td><td>" + (counter * brush_price) + "</td></tr>");
}

document.write("</table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code (you put wrong tag, it should be PHP):

```
for ( $counter++ = 10; $counter <= 100; $counter += 10)
```

It seems that you are intended to initialize $counter variable to some initial value (0, perhaps?)
$counter++ means $counter = $counter + 1, it's an expression.
You can't assign value to expression, it will throw invalid left side assignment error.

Try change to following code...

```
for ( $counter = 10; $counter <= 100; $counter += 10)
```

Javascript Equivalent:

```
var brush_price=5;
document.write('<table border="1" align="center"><tr><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th></tr>');
for(var counter=0; counter <= 100; counter+=10){
  document.write('<tr><td>'+counter+'</td></td>'+(counter*brush_price)+'</td></tr>');
}
document.write('</table>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
$brush_price = 5;
echo "<table border=\"1\" align=\"center\">";
echo "<tr><th>Quantity</th>";
echo "<th>Price</th></tr>";

for ( $count = 1, $counter=10; $count <= 10; $count++,$counter += 10) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $count;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $brush_price * $counter;
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```